# reading from binary file in numpy or pandas (Matlab code available)

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, numpy

I have a **binary file** that I could read it using this **Matlab code**:

```
fid = fopen(path);
a = fread(fid,10e6,"float");
```

What is the **equivalent code** in Python using **Numpy or Pandas** libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for this:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html